# Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error on ui.boostrap dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have been banging my head against the wall for a while now on this. I am trying to include UI-Bootstrap with my angular application. Unfortunately I keep getting this error when I try to include the ui.bootstrap dependency.

```
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module filtraApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=u...)
    at Error (native)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:38:391
    at n (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:7:333)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:37:488)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:38:134
    at n (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:7:333)
    at g (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:37:488)
    at eb (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:41:249)
    at c (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:19:463
```

Here is the top of my index.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Filtra</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"/>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-0.14.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And here is the top of my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("filtraApp", ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I am happy to include more code if it helps? I should note that the whole application works as soon as I switch to this in my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("filtraApp", []);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to not use self-closing script tags for the angular library

Comment: Where do you declare your `ngApp`?

Comment: Could you please use the non-minified version of angularjs so that the error becomes more clearer.

Comment: try to include this CDN https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

Comment: I switched to the non minified version of angular and this is the resulting error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.bootstrap

Comment: I removed the self closing tags and switched to the cloud flare link for ui-bootstrap and the bug went away. Thanks guys!